# Django/Python UserWarning Error

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error/warning, which is annoying, and wanted to see if I can fix it, but I'm not sure where to start (I'm a newbie):

```
/home/simi/workspace/hssn_svn/hssn/../hssn/log/loggers.py:28: UserWarning: ERROR: Could not configure logging
  warnings.warn('ERROR: Could not configure logging', UserWarning)
```

I'm getting this when I do:

```
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py syncdb
python manane.py shell
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
--simi

Comment: Probably not Django related. Traceback gives you the file and line number where the exception is raised.

Comment: There are three commands there. Which one gives the error?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.... When I run either of those commands, the same warning error displays.

Comment: The message there is giving you a file and a line number -- ../hssn/log/loggers.py, line 28. What's on that line (and around it)? Is that your code? Or someone else's library?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have write permissions to all the files within the application you are working with.  Also make sure you have everything in settings.py setup correctly, make sure specified paths exist and you have permissions.